# How to solve nvidia-driver-525 dependencies

Tags: apt, 18.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-525 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-525 (= 525.89.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-525:i386 (= 525.89.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```